# How to read object datas to the request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to POST datas with an Axios Post in VueJS and receive datas in a request via Laravel.
All the system is good because I'm trying to modify the code.
I need to Post an array or object in the POST like this :

My postData who passed in the body in the VueJS via Axios method POST  :

```
 postDatas = [ File => (array 2), Hello => " Contains something" ]
```

And trying to get datas in Laravel :

```
private function something(Request $request) {       
       Log::debug($request);
}
```

What I have in the Log :

```
 'File' => [object Object], ( or [object File] when it's an array )
 'Hello' => 'Contains something'
```

I'm trying to do :

```
 json_encode(postData) before the POST;
 json_decode($request['File']) after the $request method;
 Transform Array to Object
 Insert Object to Array 
 Post in Array
 Post in object
```

I don't know how to read the value of File.

Thx to help me guys

Comment: what is the exact issue you're getting? Have you tried to print `$request->all()`?

Comment: Yes I have tried but I got the same issue. I need to Upload multiple files. 
I find something else : I use the Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile and maybe this is the problem. The function can't manage the upload of multiple files

Comment: Try make changes in blade file for `<input type="files" name="file[]" />` and print your `request` data in controller. and check `getClientOriginalName()` with loop. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**VueJS**

```
const config = {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
  }

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.file);
  formData.append('text', this.text);

  axios
    .post('Your URL', formData, config)
    .then(( data ) => {
      console.log(data);

    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);

    })
```

**Laravel/PHP**

```
private function something(Request $request) {

   $fileName = time().$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
   $textName = $request->input('text');
   
   //You can check the data by DD example
   dd($textName); //dd($fileName)

   //You can also save or move the file by
   $request->file->move(public_path('storage/'), $fileName);

}
```